# Create a feature based on coordinates previously saved in localStorage OL3

Tags: javascript, jquery, gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am creating a feature when a user clicks a button that will create a feature and save their location into `localStorage()` using `geolocation()`. If the user then refreshes the page, or navigates to a different page and they come back, I want it to re-draw that feature. For some reason this does not work, I am not getting any console errors. It seems to break whenever I add the `localStorage` version to the source.

Here is where I draw it the first time on my click function

```
var coords = geolocation.getPosition();
swal("Your location has been pinned! " + coords)
var parkedCar = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coords)
})
localStorage.setItem("parkedCarCoords", coords);
parkedCar.setId("parkedCar");
parkedCar.setStyle(styleNS.styleFunction(styleConfig.parkedCarStyle));
geoLocationSource.addFeature(parkedCar);
```

And here is where I am checking for it on page load and trying to draw the feature

```
if (localStorage.getItem("parkedCarCoords")) {
        var parkedCar = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point([localStorage.getItem("parkedCarCoords")])
        })
        parkedCar.setId("parkedCar");
        parkedCar.setStyle(styleNS.styleFunction(styleConfig.parkedCarStyle));
        geoLocationSource.addFeature(parkedCar);
    }
```

When I try and do this, the feature won't show up at all, from either my click function or my localStorage.

I tried to add the localStorage version to it's own source but that yielded the same result. The click function will work if I get rid of the `geoLocationSource.addFeature(parkedCar);` line from the localStorage version.  It may also be worth noting that I have a geolocation tracking feature on the same layer, and it does not show up either when I try implementing this localStorage feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it goes wrong when you try to retrieve the coordinates from the localStorage. When you set and get the coordinates in localStorage, they are converted to a string. You are passing this string to Point, which expects an Array as input.

```
localStorage.setItem('coords', [1,1]);

localStorage.getItem('coords');
// Returns: "1,1" instead of [1,1]

// To pass these coordinates to a Point, use the split function
var coords = localStorage.getItem('coords').split(',');
new ol.geom.Point(coords);
```

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` object store item in string format so when you do `localStorage.setItem("parkedCarCoords", [1, 2]);` you store the string `1,2` not the array object.

In the same way when you do `localStorage.getItem("parkedCarCoords");` you receive the string `1,2` so `[localStorage.getItem("parkedCarCoords")]` is equal to `["1,2"]`.

You need to split the result of `getItem` to have an array of coordinates:

```
var parkedCar = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(localStorage.getItem("parkedCarCoords").split(','))
 })
```